# Do suggested edits review audits capture all bad reviewers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-audits

I've got many suggested edit review audits, and all of them were bad edits and the expected behaviour was to *Reject Edit*.

Is this *status-by-design*? Aren't there any good edits to *Approve* in audits? How would these kind of audits **capture the reviewers who reject good edits**?

Comment: Most robo reviewers simply click approve mindlessly till they get tripped up by audits. Clicking on reject mindlessly is less of a problem apparently.

Comment: Audits for edit suggestions are not easy to create.  The machine fakes an edit by intentionally putting random phrases in the text.  Almost impossible to fail such an audit, but surely has been done.

Comment: @RobertLongson The real problem would be the robo reviewers gaming the system by rejecting all edits just to increase their total reviews in order to get [Custodian](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/80/custodian), [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) and [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) badges. An audit's intention should be to catch all kinds of bad reviewers.

Comment: @HansPassant We could take some already rejected edits and show them in audits. Not just every rejected edit, may be edits which have been rejected by experienced reviewers.

Comment: There is no "we", it has to be done by SO programmers.  Every feature request for code that has been around for many years starts at minus 10,000 points.  You have to get it above zero, quite hard to do.

Comment: @HansPassant By _"we"_ I meant whoever does these kind of changes to the system. I've added the _feature-request_ tag, let's give it a shot.